# Dynamically replace img src attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am trying to replace the img source of a given source using jQuery. For example, when the image src is smith.gif, replace to johnson.gif. If williams.gif replace to brown.gif etc.

**EDIT: The images are retrieved from an XML to a random order, without class to each .**

This is what I tried:

```
if ( $("img").attr('src', 'http://example.com/smith.gif') ) {
              $(this).attr('src', 'http://example.com/johnson.gif');
            }
if ( $("img").attr('src', 'http://example.com/williams.gif') ) {
              $(this).attr('src', 'http://example.com/brown.gif');
            }
```

Note that my HTML has many images. For example

```
<img src="http://example.com/smith.gif">
<img src="http://example.com/williams.gif">
<img src="http://example.com/chris.gif">
```

etc.

So, how can I replace the images: **IF img src="http://example.com/smith.gif" then show "http://example.com/williams.gif".** etc...

Thanks alot

Comment: You are missing closing `"`s in your HTML example

Comment: You're using `$(img)` for checking the property, and `$(this)` for setting it. Is this really what you had in mind to do?

Comment: This is not how `attr()` works. You need to walk through each image using `.each()`

Comment: Sorry, I just typed fast the explanation

Comment: I think you need something more like this. $("img[src=http://example.com/smith.gif]")

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This is what you wanna do:

```
var oldSrc = 'http://example.com/smith.gif';
var newSrc = 'http://example.com/johnson.gif';
$('img[src="' + oldSrc + '"]').attr('src', newSrc);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This is what I was looking for. Give me 10 minutes to answer your question.

Answer (score 21):

You need to check out the `attr` method in the jQuery docs.  You are misusing it.  What you are doing within the if statements simply replaces all image tags `src` with the string specified in the 2nd parameter.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

A better way to approach replacing a series of images source would be to loop through each and check it's source.

**Example:**

```
$('img').each(function () {
  var curSrc = $(this).attr('src');
  if ( curSrc === 'http://example.com/smith.gif' ) {
      $(this).attr('src', 'http://example.com/johnson.gif');
  }
  if ( curSrc === 'http://example.com/williams.gif' ) {
      $(this).attr('src', 'http://example.com/brown.gif');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I will be using Niko's example. Less code if you won't use the var OldSrc and newSrc.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I replaced the src taq using:

```js
   $('#gmap_canvas').attr('src', newSrc);
```