# Change the image on submit in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the image of a button on clicking it. Below is my code, but it is not working. Please help me on that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Image</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Image</h1>
<p>
        <img src="C:\Users\Hrushikesh\Pictures\iCloud Photos\Downloads\2015\IMG_3695.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:256px;height:256px;">
</p>
        <button onclick="picturechange()"><img src="C:\Users\Hrushikesh\Desktop\star2.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:16px;height:16px;" id="pic1"></button>
        <script>
            function picturechange()
            {
                document.getElementById("pic1").src="C:\Users\Hrushikesh\Desktop\star1.jpg";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, make sure to check out the [**how to ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is off topic as you are asking for debugging help ([*see on-topic questions*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Also make sure to produce a reproducible example, providing a snippet of fiddle can accomplish that.

Comment: refer to similar questions on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462119/dynamically-replace-img-src-attribute-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image may not be showing up due to the following **reasons**:

- You need to add `file:///` prefix before loading any of local resources with full paths.
- You may be getting an error '**Not allowed to load local resource**' in your browser if you are running your webpage through a Web Server.

Comment: Thanks Ahsan,THe code has worked After adding the file:///

Comment: Please consider up-voting my Answer ... Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

This code should work perfectly, change it to your liking :-]

```js
window.picturechange = function() {
 document.getElementById("pic").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Example.svg/120px-Example.svg.png";
};
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Example.jpg/116px-Example.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:256px;height:256px;" id="pic">
</p>
<button onclick="picturechange()">Click Me</button>
```