# Change image with in my own tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I split my all images with `,(comma)` and if I hover to current images it must change with data-slider tag's images with fade effect. I guess I have to use array or something like that but I don't know how to do that any idea ?

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="image-box">
    <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/orta/2013-10/otel_elysee-beach-hotel_hACeSi55KFjDDK8c5dCn.jpg" data-slider="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/orta/2013-10/otel_antique-roman-palace_PTKxPVMcMAHbMLHJN3di.jpg,http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/orta/2013-12/otel_larissa-hotel_TnhYoDp7Cdg2BfuDdrZ3.jpg">
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to add my own jquery code but I have no any idea

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see any javascript on the page so how do you expect the image to change?

Comment: as I said I don't know logically what I have to do I gotta learn

Comment: Okay well can you explain what you wish to achieve from this, it might give me a better understanding of what it is you need to do to accomplish your goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question since you havent tried anything yet. I think what you are trying to ask is already answered here:

[Dynamically replace img src attribute with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462119/dynamically-replace-img-src-attribute-with-jquery)

If you decide to do it this way you can remove all your urls from the html tag into the script.