# Div has no height

Tags: html, css

Im doing a simple gallery. Its just some mini divs with decreased photos, there are 8 of them. When you click one of these a big div appears with static width (484px) and static height, but I want height to be AUTO but, when I set that, div won't appear, just a single line of borders and just this.

```
<div class="box_1">
    <div class="box_1_header">Header</div>
    <div class="box_1_content">
        <div class="baza_big_photo"></div>
        <div class="br2"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria01" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria02" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria03" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria04" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria05" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria06" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria07" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria08" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some legend: my big div where a photo with width 484px and height auto should apper, but won't - is `baza_big_photo`, small divs with clickable imgs are `baza_zdjecia`.

CSS:

```
.baza_big_photo {
   width: 484px;
   height: auto;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: block;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   margin: 3px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.baza_zdjecia {
   width: 118px;
   height: 86px;
   margin: 2px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid black;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
}
```

JS:

```
      function changePhoto(id) {
        var y = document.getElementById("baza_big_photo");
        y.style.display = "block";
        var z = "url('./assets/galeria_images/" + id + ".jpg')";
            y.style.backgroundImage = z;
            console.log(z);
    }
```

Comment: Show your JS code, probably you are changing background image instead of replace `img` tags. That's why divs don't have height (because browser doesn't know how tall is your background image).

Comment: `.baza_big_photo` is 0px height because the default height of a block element is already `auto`, which means the height will be based on the content inside the element. So this element's height is 0 because it has no content.

Comment: function changePhoto(id) {
   var y = document.getElementById("baza_big_photo");
   y.style.display = "block";
   var z = "url('./assets/galeria_images/" + id + ".jpg')";
    y.style.backgroundImage = z;
    console.log(z);
  }

Comment: That's what I was thinking, background images, there is a way to fix this only in CSS but your all images have to have the same aspect ratio.

Comment: so, any solution?

Comment: Are your images have the same aspect ratio?

Comment: @Venek can you use an `img` tag in the element instead of a `background-image`?

Comment: I could, but then I have no clue how to do it, how to replace src of img tag

Comment: aspect ratio yeah, one of them is cut in a half of height, the rest are all the same

Comment: So you have to use img tag. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7462140/3258604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the div is 0 height is block elements are 0 height by default, and without a specified height, are only as tall as the content inside of them. Since your div has no content, the height is 0.

To use an `img` tag in that div instead, which will give it content and a height that matches the `img` tag, add an `img` tag to the div, give the tag an ID so you can target it easily with JS, and set the `src` in your JS like this.

```js
 function changePhoto(id) {
     var y = document.getElementById("baza_big_photo_img");
     var z = "/assets/galeria_images/" + id + ".jpg";
     y.src = z;
 }
```

```css
.baza_big_photo {
   width: 484px;
   height: auto;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: block;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   margin: 3px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.baza_zdjecia {
   width: 118px;
   height: 86px;
   margin: 2px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid black;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_1">
    <div class="box_1_header">Header</div>
    <div class="box_1_content">
        <div class="baza_big_photo"><img src="" id="baza_big_photo_img"></div>
        <div class="br2"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria01" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria02" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria03" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria04" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria05" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria06" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria07" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="baza_zdjecia" id="tn_galeria08" onclick="changePhoto(this.id)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While others said to use img tags, I know a way to do it while still using background-images:

```
<div>

    <p class = "hiddentext">Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</p>
    <p class = "hiddentext">Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</p>
    <p class = "hiddentext">Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</p>
    <p class = "hiddentext">Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</p>

</div>
```

Then set the hidden text to invisible like this:

```
.hiddentext {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

This way, the div will have some height while being objectively empty. Also avoids using the img tag. Hope that helps!

Comment: alright, its showing but with width of these elements and no more :(

Comment: Then make the text stretch the whole line like this: <p class = "hidden text">Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</p>. You can always add more text if you need to. The text is just a method of the giving the div some height, no more.