# passing a variable from google script to to html

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to have a video play based on a random number generated in a spreadsheet.  since google sheets doesn't allow you to embed youtube videos directly I'm trying to do it through a custom dialogue box.

Here's what I have so far:

Google Script Code

```
    var PlayDes = sheet.getRange('g2').getValue();
    GameSheet.getRange('D4').setValue(TotYds1)
     var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Youtube')
        .setWidth(560)
        .setHeight(315);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
       .showModalDialog(html, PlayDes);
```

Then the HTML code is:

```
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/7WSQGD874Yc?start=8&end=18" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

I'm looking to change the video URL in the html code based on the value that's pulled from cell G2 in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JSmith for the help here's the solution I found...
Google Script side

```
 function retrieveValue(){
  spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet ID')
  sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data')
  var PlayDes = sheet.getRange('g2').getValue();
 return (sheet.getRange('g2').getValue());
```

Then on the  html side

```
<script>
  //*********************************** retrieve the URL from spreadsheet**********************************
var myValue
  function Vidurl(value)
  {
   myValue=value
   document.write('<iframe width="560" height="315" src= '+myValue+' frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen><\/iframe>');
  }
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Vidurl).retrieveValue(); 
</script>
```

One issue I had was the browser didn't like my script and was labeling it as dangerous script which I then had to over ride.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your cell is `g2`

create a script in your IDE like so:

```
function retrieveValue()
{
  ...//grab spreadsheet and sheet
  return (sheet.getRange('g2').getValue());
}
```

then call it on your HTML client side as so:

```
 <iframe id="myVideo" width="560" height="315" src="NEED VARIABLE HERE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <script>
      var myValue = null;
      function onSuccess(value)
      {
        $("#myVideo").attr('src', value);
      }
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).retrieveValue();
    </script>
```

**NOTE**

`google.script.run` is an asynchronous call so you'll have to wait the call is finished to get the desired value on the client side.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but once I have my variable passed from G2 how do I go about adding it to the iframe I'm trying to create?

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="NEED VARIABLE HERE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: well use JQuery there's a lot of documentation about this kind of thing . [an example with img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462119/dynamically-replace-img-src-attribute-with-jquery)

Comment: @ShavedApeBaby just edited my post to show you how this could be made

Comment: for the retrieval isn't working.  I know that the correct string is being returned at the end of the retirieveValue function, but its not making it to the html function. The variable myValue is null after the script is run

Comment: @ShavedApeBaby can you share with me your spreadsheet please. I'll make it work. Or an example one.

Comment: I'm new to this where can I find your email to share with you

Comment: @ShavedApeBaby just share the link in comment or in your post I'll send you a request to access. Best.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aerWWd8jDHJ7nwFHIAd0skm-Du0LtssemyyyE4Q6R8s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: tell me when you are available. I've looked at your spreadsheet and I didn't know you where calling another one.

Comment: I've got time from 9:30-10:30 today.  I've made some more comments to see if that helps to clarify the code at all

Comment: @ShavedApeBaby I'm on your spreadhsheet. please use chat . Thanks